# Association Rule mining Confidence and Support

Tags: data-mining, rule, apriori

This is a theoritical question:
When (practical or real life situations) is:-

1. Very high confidence..
2. Low confidence is of significance...
3. High support and low confidence..
4. High support and high confidence...

required?

High/low support/confidence implies high/low support or confidence threshold.

I want to know situations under which the above thresholds mat be chosen for association rule mining.

Comment: What is "high"? Depends on the data.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but rather a question about interpreting results. You might have better luck getting an answer on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)